# Jmeter maven plugin skip unit tests

Tags: java, maven, configuration, jmeter, pom.xml

I am trying to run jmeter tests with jmeter maven plugin as shown in https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Configuring-the-jvm-that-the-jmeter-process-runs-in

When I run mvn verify it runs the jmeter test but also all the unit tests under src/test/. Is there a way that I can skip unit tests and only run the jmeter test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The easiest is just [running single `jmeter` goal](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2015/03/17/apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/) like:

```
mvn jmeter:jmeter
```

this way you will run only performance tests, all other build procedures will be skipped.

A harder but more flexible way would be using [Maven Builde Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), see [Maven – How to skip unit test](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test/)

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I tried running mvn jmeter:jmeter, but it seems like with the goal it can not override the configuration for different jmeter projects.         E.g. <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
 <arguments>
 <argument>${foo1}</argument>
 <argument>${foo2}</argument>
 </arguments>
 </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
 <testFilesIncluded>
       <jMeterTestFile>${jmeterScript}</jMeterTestFile>
 </testFilesIncluded>